# Clear my confusion on PV or PQ nodes of power system with renewables?

Tags: solar-energy, mppt, power-flow-analysis

A solar PV is connected to a node of the power system through a converter circuit.

Is it possible to understand that the solar PV operating at its maximum power point (MPP) is considered a PQ node? Or a PV node, as the active power at MPP is known, as well the voltage corresponding to it?

Comment: What's a PQ node and what's a PV node?

Comment: @Andyaka PQ nodes are assigned to load buses when the active and reactive power of that bus is known, while PV nodes are those buses whose active power and voltage at the bus is known.

Comment: I'm thinking there is a "not" in there, but it slipped out.

Comment: How can the solar cell ever be regarded as anything but a DC system hence, how can it be regarded as PQ since there cannot be reactive power (even after MPPT system because it's still DC). That is why I asked for your definition.

Comment: "as the active power at MPP is known, as well the voltage corresponding to it?" Power and voltage at MPP vary, depending on light and temperature. Are you assuming a single MPP under all circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

From a steady-state power flow standpoint, PQ nodes are nodes where the active and reactive power injections or loads are specified while voltage and angle are unknowns to be solved for. PV nodes are nodes where the active power and voltage magnitude are specified while the reactive power injection or load and voltage angle are unknowns to be solved for. The "PV" stand for P=active power and V=voltage magnitude. Don't get this confused with the "PV" for photovoltaic.

The steady-state power flow is only concerned with bus voltages and active and reactive power injections or loads at the system nodes. Internal details such as the photovoltaic panels' voltage and current are not considered. The only part relevant to the power system power flow is the injected power on the grid side.

In the case of grid-connected photovoltaic generation, how to represent it in a power flow case depends on the controls of the inverter. The active power injection would be specified to be the power generated by the photovoltaic system, net of any losses in the converter. If the inverter does any voltage control at the injection bus, then the specified voltage and reactive power limits should be specified for it as a PV bus. If the inverter just injects active power and does not regulate voltage, then it should be specified as a PQ bus with the reactive power equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, PV/PQ refers to real/stored power of a voltage source such as a wind turbine as a wind turbine has rotational stored energy.

Since PV also refers to Photo Voltaic source which is a high impedance current source, it does not have have any momentum or stored or reactive energy unless you add a capacitor to it but deviating the voltage only reduces efficiency from the MPPT so PQ does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

A solar photovoltaic operating at `MPPT` can be represented as a `PQ` node. While operating in `voltage control mode`, it is represented as a`PV` node which follows the load flow model.